# How could I integrate Materialize CSS and JavaScript components into Svelte

Tags: javascript, materialize, svelte

I'm new to Svelte, and I want to build my next project with it.

I want to use Materialize for CSS and JavaScript components, but I couldn't find a way to set it up and integrate with Svelte.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the `materialize-css` package with `yarn add -D materialize-css`.

The stock Svelte template (https://github.com/sveltejs/template) has 2 CSS imports in `public/index.html`

```html
<!-- base styles -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>

<!-- styles that were defined in the components -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css'>
```

Let's adjust how the CSS is built. Instead of `global.css`, we'll merge `global.css` and `materialize/dist/materialize.css` into one file.

There is a rollup plugin called `rollup-plugin-css-only` that can do this.

`yarn add -D rollup-plugin-css-only`

In `rollup.config.js`, configure the plugin by importing it `import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only'` and add the `css({output: "public/build/base.css"})` to the list of `plugins`.

Now we can import `.css` files in `src/main.js`:

```js
import '../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'
import '../public/global.css'

// import js stuff too
import '../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize'

....

// init material plugins
M.AutoInit()
```

Don't forget to update `public/index.html` to include the generated `base.css` instead of `global.css`:

```
- <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>
+ <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/base.css'>
```

[Demo](https://github.com/joshnuss/materialize-svelte)

Comment: @josnuss what if you were using Sapper & Svelte? I'm assuming the `M.AutoInit()` and plugin would apply on the client side - correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. Materialize runs only on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed this template with Svelte + MaterializeCSS and SMUI (Svelte Material UI) >> [Svelte + MaterializeCSS + SMUI](https://github.com/rubenterre/Svelte-Materialize-SMUI)

Comment: Please explain how this relates to the question and how it works.